# mysql sleep、query end プロセスについて

Tags: mysql

DBの高負荷状態が続いたため、SHOW PROCESSLISTを実行したところ、
Command が Sleep 、また query endの状態のプロセスが多く発生していること確認できました。

上記のプロセスが増加してしまう原因および対策方法(できれば暫定と恒久)をご教示願います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep は接続されたまま何のコマンドも発行していない状態です。これが多くて困る場合はクライアントアプリの処理を見なおしたほうがいいかもしれません。クライアントアプリを終了させればその状態のスレッドは無くなりますし、サーバー側から強制的に切断したい場合は KILL コマンドを使用できます。

query end の方は、マニュアル http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/general-thread-states.html によると、

> この状態は、クエリーを処理したあと、ただし freeing items 状態の前に発生します

ということのようです。普通は長時間この状態のままということはないと思うので、もしそうなっていたら mysqld がおかしな状態になっているか、サーバーの負荷が高いのかもしれません。